# What are the steps to create domain specific query language?

Tags: dsl, dsl-tools

1. i want to create domain specific query language
2. i need steps to create it and how to transfer from the created **domain specific query language** to **normal SQL query** to execute it.
3. and any recommended tools??

Answer (score 4):

DSLs are not much related to SQL.

You first need to specify your DSL on paper. I strongly recommend reading good books about programming languages while doing that. (e.g. [Lisp in Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) by C.Queinnec).

Then you need to implement your DSL as an interpreter. You'll use standard [lexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexing), [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and [interpreters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) (or possibly [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)) techniques. Very probably you'll need to use or implement a [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collector_%28computer_science%29) (or use [Boehm's GC](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/)). Parsers generators like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) could help you.

Co-designing and implementing your DSL in parallel is usually a good way of working.

You really should read several books & papers on several languages before designing & implementing your own DSL.

A practical way to do that is to **embed an existing interpreter** like [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) into your application, or to **embed your application inside an interpreter** like [ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/) or [python](http://python.org/)

Designing and implementing a good DSL is not trivial (several months or years of work), and requires some computer science & programming culture & know-how. Perhaps reading proceedings of conferences like [DSL2011](https://dsl2011.bordeaux.inria.fr/) will help you.

In addition of C.Queinnec's book, you could also read [Programming Languages: Principles and Paradigms (by Maurizio Gabbrielli & Simone Martini)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848829132) & [Seven Languages in Seven Weeks: A Pragmatic Guide to Learning Programming Languages (by Tate)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193435659X) & [Programmming Language Pragmatics (by M.Scott)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123745144)

Comment: i read about xtext of eclipse and i understood that it offers parser and lexer ... my problem is what is the step after??

Comment: The next step is reading a lot of papers & books, learning several existing DSLs, and thinking. Lexing & parsing is the very easy part.